# Possible to have two NSWindowController in the same app?

Tags: objective-c, macos, nswindowcontroller

I am noobie on mac os x development. I have been an iOS developer and recently started playing with a mac os x demo app. What I am doing is simple, I created a new application it has a main.storyboard with a windows controller and a view controller. I then created a new storyboard add a windows view controller which comes with its view controller. I give the windows controller a identifier, tie a menu item to a method in the app delegate like :

```
NSStoryboard *storyBoard = [NSStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil]; // get a reference to the storyboard
NSWindowController *storeOpsWC = [storyBoard instantiateControllerWithIdentifier:@"TestVC"]; // instantiate your window controller
[storeOpsWC showWindow:self]; // show the window
```

I run the app. The original Window shows up as expected. I then hit my menu item and the second window shows up, but as soon as I tap the first window the new window disappears! what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your description. I created a new window controller from storyboard, created a new menu item hooked that item up to the Windowcontroller, and it work.
If you need a reference to the window controller, do it like in iOS with the segue sender.[image]